# 2 range slider change values with drop-down menu

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 range sliders and a drop-down menu. The drop-down menu is metric and imperial and when it is changed, the units and values of the range slider has to change from (degC and m) to (degF and ft). A stackoverflow user helped me get the the temperature slider working and I thought I could replicate the code for the elevation range slider, but now both are broken. Why?

```
<p>
  <label id="tempunitresult" for "temp">Temperature (<span id="tempUnitString"></span>):</label>
  <input type="range" id="tempselected" class="slider">
</p>
<p>
  <label id="elevunitresult" for"elev">Elevation (<span id="elevUnitString"></span>):</label> 
  <input type="range" id="elevselected" class="slider">
</p>

<p>
  <label for="unittype">Units:</label>
  <select id="unitselected">
    <option value="metric">Metric (Celsius)</option>
    <option value="imperial">Imperial (Fahrenheit)</option>
  </select>
</p>

<p><span id="rangeValueTemp">0</span><span id="tempUnitStringCurrent">&thinsp;</span></p>
<p><span id="rangeValueElev">0</span><span id="elevUnitStringCurrent">&thinsp;</span></p>
```

```
input,
select {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

label {
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
}
```

```
let unitSelected = document.getElementById('unitselected');
let tempValue = document.getElementById("tempselected");
let rangeValueTemp = document.getElementById("rangeValueTemp");
let tempUnitString = document.getElementById("tempUnitString");
let tempUnitStringCurrent = document.getElementById("tempUnitStringCurrent");

let elevValue = document.getElementById("elevselected");
let rangeValueElev = document.getElementById("rangeValueElev");
let elevUnitString = document.getElementById("elevUnitString");
let elevUnitStringCurrent = document.getElementById("elevUnitStringCurrent");

// metric values
let minCelsius = -29;
let maxCelsius = 43;
let stepsCelsius = 18;
let initialValue = 7;

let minMeters = 0;
let maxMeters = 1500;
let stepsMeters = 750;
let elevinitialValue = 750;

// imperial values
let minFahrenheit = minCelsius * 9 / 5 + 32;
let maxFahrenheit = maxCelsius * 9 / 5 + 32;
let stepsFahrenheit = 32.4;

let minFeet = minMeters * 3.28084;
let maxFeet = maxMeters * 3.28084;
let stepsFeet = stepsMeters / 2;

//default values
let tempString = '°C';
tempUnitString.textContent = tempString;
tempUnitStringCurrent.textContent = tempString;
tempselected.setAttribute('min', minCelsius);
tempselected.setAttribute('max', maxCelsius);
tempselected.setAttribute('step', stepsCelsius);
tempselected.value = initialValue;

let elevString = 'm';
elevUnitString.textContent = elevString;
elevUnitStringCurrent.textContent = elevString;
elevselected.setAttribute('min', minMeters);
elevselected.setAttribute('max', maxMeters);
elevselected.setAttribute('step', stepsMeters);
elevselected.value = elevinitialValue;

let unitType = +unitselected.value;
let currentTemp = +tempselected.value;
let currentElev = +elevselected.value;
rangeValueTemp.textContent = currentTemp;
rangeValueElev.textContent = currentElev;

//update elevation values
elevValue.addEventListener('change', function(e)){
  currentElev = +e.currentTarget.value;
  rangeValueElev.textContent = currentElev;
}

//update temperature values
tempValue.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  currentTemp = +e.currentTarget.value;
  rangeValueTemp.textContent = currentTemp;
})

//update temperature units 
unitSelected.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  currentTemp = +tempselected.value;
  currentElev = +elevselected.value;

  unitType = e.currentTarget.value;
  if (unitType == 'imperial') {
    tempString = '°F';
    elevString = 'ft';

    currentTemp = currentTemp * 9 / 5 + 32;
    tempValue.setAttribute('step', stepsFahrenheit);
    tempValue.setAttribute('min', minFahrenheit);
    tempValue.setAttribute('max', maxFahrenheit);

    currentElev = currentElev * 3.28084;
    elevValue.setAttribute('step', stepsFeet);
    elevValue.setAttribute('min', minFeet);
    elevValue.setAttribute('max', maxFeet);

} else {
    tempString = '°C';
    elevString = 'm';

    currentTemp = (currentTemp - 32) * 5 / 9;
    tempValue.setAttribute('min', minCelsius);
    tempValue.setAttribute('max', maxCelsius);
    tempValue.setAttribute('step', stepsCelsius);

    currentElev = currentElev / 3.28084;
    elevValue.setAttribute('min', minMeters);
    elevValue.setAttribute('max', maxMeters);
    elevValue.setAttribute('step', stepsMeters);

  }

  currentTemp = +currentTemp.toFixed(3);
  currentElev = +currentTemp.toFixed(4);
  rangeValueTemp.textContent = currentTemp;
  rangeValueElev.textContent = currentElev;
  tempUnitString.textContent = tempString;
  tempUnitStringCurrent.textContent = tempString;
  elevUnitString.textContent = elevString;
  elevUnitStringCurrent.textContent = elevString;
  tempselected.value = currentTemp;
  elevselected.value = currentElev;

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    // You have error at line 49 & syntax error at line 56. I have corrected & tested it. It seems working fine. Thanks

    let unitSelected = document.getElementById('unitselected');
    let tempValue = document.getElementById("tempselected");
    let rangeValueTemp = document.getElementById("rangeValueTemp");
    let tempUnitString = document.getElementById("tempUnitString");
    let tempUnitStringCurrent = document.getElementById("tempUnitStringCurrent");

    let elevValue = document.getElementById("elevselected");
    let rangeValueElev = document.getElementById("rangeValueElev");
    let elevUnitString = document.getElementById("elevUnitString");
    let elevUnitStringCurrent = document.getElementById("elevUnitStringCurrent");

    // metric values
    let minCelsius = -29;
    let maxCelsius = 43;
    let stepsCelsius = 18;
    let initialValue = 7;

    let minMeters = 0;
    let maxMeters = 1500;
    let stepsMeters = 750;
    let elevinitialValue = 750;

    // imperial values
    let minFahrenheit = minCelsius * 9 / 5 + 32;
    let maxFahrenheit = maxCelsius * 9 / 5 + 32;
    let stepsFahrenheit = 32.4;

    let minFeet = minMeters * 3.28084;
    let maxFeet = maxMeters * 3.28084;
    let stepsFeet = stepsMeters / 2;

    //default values
    let tempString = '°C';
    tempUnitString.textContent = tempString;
    tempUnitStringCurrent.textContent = tempString;
    tempselected.setAttribute('min', minCelsius);
    tempselected.setAttribute('max', maxCelsius);
    tempselected.setAttribute('step', stepsCelsius);
    tempselected.value = initialValue;

    let elevString = 'm';
    elevUnitString.textContent = elevString;
    elevUnitStringCurrent.textContent = elevString;
    elevselected.setAttribute('min', minMeters);
    elevselected.setAttribute('max', maxMeters);
    elevselected.setAttribute('step', stepsMeters);
    elevselected.value = elevinitialValue;

    let unitType = +unitSelected.value; // Error: +unitselected.value
    let currentTemp = +tempselected.value;
    let currentElev = +elevselected.value;
    rangeValueTemp.textContent = currentTemp;
    rangeValueElev.textContent = currentElev;

    //update elevation values
    elevValue.addEventListener('change', function (e) { // Error: ('change', function(e)){
      currentElev = +e.currentTarget.value;
      rangeValueElev.textContent = currentElev;
    })

    //update temperature values
    tempValue.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
      currentTemp = +e.currentTarget.value;
      rangeValueTemp.textContent = currentTemp;
    })

    //update temperature units 
    unitSelected.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
      currentTemp = +tempselected.value;
      currentElev = +elevselected.value;

      unitType = e.currentTarget.value;
      if (unitType == 'imperial') {
        tempString = '°F';
        elevString = 'ft';

        currentTemp = currentTemp * 9 / 5 + 32;
        tempValue.setAttribute('step', stepsFahrenheit);
        tempValue.setAttribute('min', minFahrenheit);
        tempValue.setAttribute('max', maxFahrenheit);

        currentElev = currentElev * 3.28084;
        elevValue.setAttribute('step', stepsFeet);
        elevValue.setAttribute('min', minFeet);
        elevValue.setAttribute('max', maxFeet);

      } else {
        tempString = '°C';
        elevString = 'm';

        currentTemp = (currentTemp - 32) * 5 / 9;
        tempValue.setAttribute('min', minCelsius);
        tempValue.setAttribute('max', maxCelsius);
        tempValue.setAttribute('step', stepsCelsius);

        currentElev = currentElev / 3.28084;
        elevValue.setAttribute('min', minMeters);
        elevValue.setAttribute('max', maxMeters);
        elevValue.setAttribute('step', stepsMeters);

      }

      currentTemp = +currentTemp.toFixed(3);
      currentElev = +currentElev.toFixed(4);
      rangeValueTemp.textContent = currentTemp;
      rangeValueElev.textContent = currentElev;
      tempUnitString.textContent = tempString;
      tempUnitStringCurrent.textContent = tempString;
      elevUnitString.textContent = elevString;
      elevUnitStringCurrent.textContent = elevString;
      tempselected.value = currentTemp;
      elevselected.value = currentElev;

    });
```

Comment: Thank you for catching those mistakes. The range slider is still not working correctly. When you toggle from metric to imperial, the output value for elevation goes haywire. The elevation output value changes to the temperature output value and moves the range slider toggle all the way to the left instead of staying at the last inputted value. The value only updates when you move the toggle. How can this be fixed?

Comment: There is another error at line 103, currentElev = +currentTemp.toFixed(4);. I have changed to currentElev = +currentElev.toFixed(4);  & tested it. The slider will stay when changing selection, some differences because of the m to ft conversion and your elevation step. Try change to this, let stepsFeet = stepsMeters * 3.28084; All will be precise already. Thanks

Comment: Thank you! It works exactly how I wanted it to